# Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error here is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
     $projTit=mysql_escape_string($_POST['projecttitle']);
     $projCat=mysql_escape_string($_POST['projectcategory']);
     $budget=intval(mysql_escape_string($_POST['budget']));
     $description=mysql_escape_string($_POST['editor1']);
     $query=sprintf("insert into projects value('%s','%s','%s',%d)",
            $projTit,$description,$projCat,$budget);
     if (!mysql_query($query)){
         die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
         }
        echo '<p class="record">Your Record has been Added<p>';
    }

    ?>
```

I have tried to write %d in `''` but still not working.

[image]

Comment: What is your table structure? If you don't specify a column set you must provide values for all columns.

Comment: @Interrobang sorry i didn't understand what is a column set  let me show my table structure

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you don't specify which columns you are inserting into (using syntax like `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3)`) then you must specify values for *all* columns :)

Comment: @Interrobang i have edit and showed my table i am providing values for all column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your table has five columns. However, you are not providing a value for the `Project_Id` column. This gives you the error you mentioned.

I understand that you're not providing a value since it's likely a `PRIMARY KEY` that autoincrements. To tell MySQL that you are intentionally not passing a value for that column, **you should add `NULL` as the first value.**

```
value(NULL, '%s','%s','%s',%d)
```

However, you really should specifically name which columns you are inserting into in case you add a new column at a future date.

```
INSERT INTO projects (col1, col2, col3, col4) value ('%s','%s','%s',%d)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should **really** specify the column names or your app will break if you add a column later, even if it has a useable default value:

```
INSERT INTO projects
    (Project_Title, Project_Description, Project_Category, Project_Budget)
VALUES
    (...)
```

Especially since you have an `auto_increment` ID column it makes sense; otherwise you'd always have to specify it as `NULL` in your query.

The easiest (but also ugliest) fix would thus be:

```
$query=sprintf("insert into projects value (null, '%s','%s','%s',%d)",
        $projTit,$description,$projCat,$budget);
```

The good fix would be this:

```
$query = sprintf("
    INSERT INTO projects
        (Project_Title, Project_Description, Project_Category, Project_Budget)
    VALUES
        ('%s', '%s', '%s', %d)
    ", $projTit,$description,$projCat,$budget);
```

By the way, consider using PDO - then you can use something similar to a format string but don't have to deal with escaping.

Comment: Wrong. "VALUE is a synonym for VALUES in this context. Neither implies anything about the number of values lists, and either may be used whether there is a single values list or multiple lists." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: by not specifying column name and changing value to values is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

try naming the columns you want to fill like

```
insert into projects (col1, col2, col3) values (...)
```

Comment: yes naming the columns i am able to add values thanks for help.